# WATIR: faker gem not working

Tags: cucumber, watir, faker

I have module **module FakeText**

```
require 'faker'
require 'xkcd'

module FakeText
  def generate_title
    "Auto Title: #{Faker::Commerce.department} #{get_current_time}"
  end
```

I am using it as:

```
require_relative '../../lib/helpers/text_generator'

class TitlePage
include PageObject

  def add_new_title
    $title_text = generate_title
    self.title_element.send_keys($title_text)
  end
```

but it gives error:

```
NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `generate_title'
```

Comment: I don't see `include FakeTest` in your code example.

Comment: its here `require_relative '../../lib/helpers/text_generator'`. `text_generator.rb` is lying in `lib/helpers` directory

Comment: @paul, requiring the file is different than including the module.

Comment: Its working now. I was using `require_all gem` thought it would help in include.